# Access to "media keys" from within a browser tab

Tags: javascript, browser, google-chrome

Is there a way to access the "media keys" with Javascript from within a browser tab/window?

I am mainly interested in a google chrome solution.

Using the following code, there doesn't seem to be an event generated for the media keys:

```
<html>
<body onKeyDown="showKeyCode(event)">
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function showKeyCode(event) {
            alert(event.keyCode);
        }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Am I missing something?  Could I do better with a Google Chrome extension??

**Update:**  to address this problem I crafted the following tools:

- Chrome [MusicMan](https://github.com/jldupont/ChromeMusicMan)
- [Mediakeys Server](https://github.com/jldupont/MediaKeysServer)

Comment: Do you mean the keyboard keys for altering system volume, mute, etc.?  (If so, I would hope and expect that javascript within a browser wouldn't have access to that; seems like that would enable some fairly evil exploits.)

Comment: @JacobM: Yes those. About the exploit potential: I am not sure what is the concern here. I am talking about intercepting the "keydown" event like any other key.  What is your concern?

Comment: Oh, I thought you meant triggering those functions from within javascript.  Intercepting "keydown" doesn't seem like a problem.

Comment: @JacobMattison if you still use StackOverflow, could you update the answer? Thakis' answer is much more recent than mine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit**: There is now explicit support for media keys. The answer below is deprecated. See @thakis answer below.

## Old 2012 answer

Regarding whether you could do better than a Chrome Extension: no you could not - I've made a content script for a site, and running it within the current stable release of Chrome 16 on OS X 10.7. The script is simple enough:

```
console.log('Content script loading');

$("body").bind("keyup",function(event){
    console.log(event.keyCode);
})
```

And it shows that **no events are triggered for the back, play/pause, forward, mute, volume down or volume up keys**.

Interesting the unused F5 key goes generate a keycode, so you could potentially use it as an alternative if you wish.

Comment: @jldupont Interesting re: installing a native app to catch the keypresses, and using that to communicate with a server for the extension. The F5 option is obviously not as neat for the end user as proper play/pause, but it is less work to implement for the developer. Hopefully one day they'll give us proper access!

Answer (score 19):

As of Chrome 73, there's explicit support for media keys, see https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/02/chrome-73-media-updates

In summary, you can install an event handler with

```
navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('previoustrack', function() {
  // User hit "Previous Track" key.
});
```

The document above gives a good overview.

https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/media-session/ has example code and a demo.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Media_Session_API has more detailed documentation.

Comment: I've been looking for that documentation for about 3 months now!  thank you!

Comment: Thanks for this! Unfortunately (but not surprisingly), Safari doesn't implement this.

Answer (score 8):

The answer from Thakis appears to be the most current.

Outdated Answer from a decade ago:

Here's a [list of key codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd375731(VS.85).aspx) from Microsoft; they include keys such as "VK_VOLUME_MUTE".  The key code for VK_VOLUME_MUTE is listed as 0xAD.  0xAD is decimal is 173.

And sure enough, when I load the following and hit the mute button on my keyboard, the key code reported is 173.  So they do work like any other key; it wouldn't surprise me, though, if the key codes are Windows-specific.  It may take some experimenting.

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).keydown(function(ev){
       alert(ev.keyCode);
    });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ah; I tried it on Chrome/Windows.  Yeah, like I said, it's probably OS-specific.  Do you get no keydown event firing on Linux, or are you getting a different keycode?

Comment: Do the keys work otherwise -- I mean, do they actually change the volume, etc.?  If so, you may be out of luck; if there's no event, there's no event.  But if not, perhaps you're missing a driver?

Comment: Ditto Chrome on OS X - media keys do not generate keycodes in Chrome. The media keys do work in other apps. So it looks like this solution works, but only for Windows.

Answer (score 3):

As it seems, there is now a possibility to execute JS code on media key presses.
I took [mikemaccana's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9168544/9634099) and looked up the [KeyEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent):

```js
$(ready);

function ready() {
  $(document).on('keydown', onKeyDown);
}

function onKeyDown(ev) {
  if (ev.code === 'MediaPlayPause') alert('Play/Pause');
  if (ev.code === 'MediaStop') alert('Stop');
  if (ev.code === 'MediaTrackPrevious') alert('Previous Track');
  if (ev.code === 'MediaTrackNext') alert('Next Track');    
  if (ev.code === 'VolumeUp') alert('Volume Up');
  if (ev.code === 'VolumeDown') alert('Volume Down');
  if (ev.code === 'VolumeMute') alert('Volume Mute');
}
```

You can just do `alert(ev.code);` in `onKeyDown` to get the key codes.

I uploaded this example on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Trojaner/0jpLxrat/6/) so you can test it.