# Capture a keyboard KNOB events in javascript

Tags: javascript, keyboard

I have a DELL keyboard sk-8135 with a volume knob,
and I want to capture the knob events using javascript...

[image]

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Is any keyboard event fired, when you press that button? See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent

Comment: If I turn the knob, no key events are fired... I also tried many online javascript key testers... but never see any event fire...

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630191/access-to-media-keys-from-within-a-browser-tab

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan It is a KNOB, not a button xD

Comment: @neoDev but hopefully you got the point :D

Answer (score -1):

If you are pressing on knob try it in this form  (may be rolling works too): [javascript.info test stand](http://javascript.info/tutorial/keyboard-events#test-stand-test-stand). I can capture my volume buttons there.