# Key press detection without focus

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox, web

Fast question:

On a website, there is any way to detect when a keyboard key is pressed while the browser is minimized? or when you have the focus on another window?

For example, you open my website on Chrome, and you switch to Spotify for example, I need to detect if the user press a particular key that he previously binded.

I can imagine that's impossible with javascript because you have no focus on the browser, but, there is any way for it? Making a chrome extension maybe? with Java? Silverlight?

I just need to detect the user pressed the key, nothing else.

Thanks!

EDIT:

My users have already installed a C# app on their computers, can I (maybe) detect the key press in the App and call the browser (which is already opened) in any way?

Comment: I think so the keyboard event will helps you   .In this method you could find specific key.                                    http://googleweblight.com/?lite_url=http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_key_which.asp&ei=itKZ_LaG&lc=en-IN&s=1&m=924&host=www.google.co.in&ts=1463937610&sig=APY536xCuX4Y18qrMvqIZLAgO0TEMByZeA

Comment: The problem is detect the event when you have no focus on the website.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible, although it should be.

The motivation for why it is not possible is perfectly reasonable. There is no doubt that untrusted webpages should not be able to monitor keyboard activity, as this would allow malicious webpages to monitor confidential activity.

However, there are also perfectly legitimate use cases for being able to do this. A good example is a voice communication Web app. It would be useful for such an app to detect when a particular key is pressed, to provide push-to-talk and other keybindings. But this is not currently possible. Indeed, the Discord Web app has to request that users download the desktop version of the app to use push-to-talk effectively.

The reasonable solution would be to allow Web apps to request permission from the user to monitor all or some keyboard activity when out of focus. This is how location, camera, and other sensitive permissions already work. By default, webpages would not have the permission, and so security would be assured for untrusted webpages. This would be an important improvement for the Web as it seeks to expand its relevance to desktop and mobile environments.

Comment: I am using pandora on Chrome browser, I have a MAC and on the mac keyboard you can press the play and pause button, somehow in pandora it works out the the browser window...

Comment: @Vidal Media keys are implemented differently than regular keys: the browser listens for them at the OS level, then exposes a JS API (different from the keypress events) to let pages listen for them. [More Info/Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59241141/884734). A bit late for the OP, but the media keys might actually be a good solution since they are already set up for this "global listen" behavior. I think it'll work for the usecase that led me to this SE question.

Answer (score -3):

Basically you want a keylogger... and no, it's not possible, luckily.

Comment: Do not accuse without knowing what you're talking.

Comment: Excuse me if you felt accuse but it wasn't the point. Just a reminder that the feature you're asking for would meant privacy intrusion and that's the reason why it's not possible.